# NGINX Proxy Manager and Plesk Obsidian

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, web-hosting, plesk

I am searching for an easy way to setup reverse proxy with nginx proxy manager in combination with Plesk (Obsidian) - how can I do this easy? WHenenver I disable nginx in plesk to use nginx proxy manager the Apache server takes over and interferes. But I dont want to disable the apache as I have websites hosted

Is there a way to easily change the ports used by apache ? I tried changing the apache config variables but not sure how

Thanks! :)

Rob

Comment: Please see [this meta Q&A](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8055/what-should-server-fault-do-with-questions-about-web-hosting-control-panels). In short, you've found what's a common problem with such panels: they mangle the config. It's off topic on Serverfault for that very reason.

Comment: https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/advanced-administration-guide-linux/virtual-hosts-configuration/changing-virtual-hosts-settings-using-configuration-templates/example-changing-default-apache-ports.68800/#:~:text=To%20change%20the%20Apache%20HTTP,for%20example%3A%20%223456%22%20. maybe this can help you